# How to avoid C# replace to replace the new string again by second replace

Tags: c#, replace

Let's say that I want to replace the phrases "First Name" and "Name" both of them to "#First Name".

For example:

```
string text = "first name and name should be with # as prefix and suffix";
text = text.Replace("first name", "#first name#");
text = text.Replace("name", "#name#");
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

I would like that the output will be: "#first name# and #name# should be with # as prefix and suffix"

but the second replace replacing also the replaced text so the "name" that inside the phrase #first name# replaced again: #first #name## and #name# should be with # as prefix and suffix.

Is there an option to protect the phrases that starts and ends with # or do the replace in "one shoot" for both of the phrases?

Thanks.

After the first replace:
"my full name is my #first name# and my last name together"

Answer (score 6):

Use an intermediate value:

```
string text = "first name and name should be with # as prefix and suffix";
text = text.Replace("first name", "#SOME_UNIQUE_CODE#");
text = text.Replace("name", "#name#");
text = text.Replace("#SOME_UNIQUE_CODE#", "#first name#");
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Or use a regular expression replace.

Answer (score 3):

If that code is literal, use string.Format.

```
string.Format("{0} and {1} should be with # as prefix and suffix", "#first name#", "#name#");
```

You could also reverse the ordering and include the replaced text in any overlapping replaces:

```
string text = "first name and name should be with # as prefix and suffix";
text = text.Replace("name", "#name#");
text = text.Replace("first #name#", "#first name#");
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: I'm sure OP wants to use the code for more input than only given string.

Comment: Edited and added a new approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace(input, "(first\ name|name)", match => {
 if (match.Value == "name") return "#name#";
 else if (match.Value == "first name") return "#first name#";
 else throw new InvalidOperationException("bug");
});
```

Use a Regex to match all possible strings at once, then decide in the match evaluator what to replace with. This approach is very extensible and not a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex that only replaces occurrences of `name` without a `#` in front or after it:

```
string text = "first name and name should be with # as prefix and suffix";
text = text.Replace("first name", "#first name#");
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"([^\#])(name)([^\#])", "$1#$2#$3");
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Output:

```
#first name# and #name# should be with # as prefix and suffix
```

Answer (score -3):

Use regular expressions.. here's a ruby snippet. The translation to C# should be simple

```
> puts str.gsub( /(first\s)?name/ , "#\\0#") 

=> #first name# and #name# should be with # as prefix and suffix
```